# SELECT COUNT inside SELECT COUNT

Tags: mysql

I am trying this code.

```
SELECT COUNT(SELECT COUNT(postnID) AS Total,
 postnID, Unit_DBM, job_type, 
 level, internal_plantilla, INCID,
 ITEM_NO_2005, position_type, 
 position_status 
 FROM plantilla 
 GROUP BY internal_plantilla, level, INCID, postnID, position_status       
 ORDER BY internal_plantilla, postnID) as num 
 FROM plantilla
```

But having error in mysql. How can I perform select count inside a select count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do by:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from (SELECT COUNT(postnID) AS Total,
 postnID, Unit_DBM, job_type, 
 level, internal_plantilla, INCID,
 ITEM_NO_2005, position_type, 
 position_status 
 FROM plantilla 
 GROUP BY internal_plantilla, level, INCID, postnID, position_status       
 ORDER BY internal_plantilla, postnID) as num
```

Comment: Your answer results to 1. I am trying to determine the count for the query inside so I can use it in array.

Comment: @ylleigh12 replace count(*) with Total, like I updated answer

Comment: @ylleigh12 but why all of this you can select count directly

Comment: I can just use: SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM plantilla because they have the same result. But not the result I am expecting.

Comment: @ylleigh12 what the result you expect, your question not clear at all